# How do you implement Drag and Drop for video instead of image?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I cant seem to implement a Drag and Drop Function for video files (.mp4), only images. Everytime I try to drag a video, the program crashed. Here is the drop canvas I had:

```
private async void mainCanvas_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Width = 200;
        img.Height = 150;
        BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        {
            var storageItems = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
            foreach (StorageFile file in storageItems)
            {
                var stream = await
               file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                await bm.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                img.Source = bm;
            }
            img.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
            img.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
            img.ManipulationStarted += mPlayer_ManipulationStarted;
            img.ManipulationCompleted += mPlayer_ManipulationCompleted;
            img.ManipulationDelta += mPlayer_ManipulationDelta;
            mainCanvas.Children.Add(img);
            Canvas.SetLeft(img, e.GetPosition(mainCanvas).X);
            Canvas.SetTop(img, e.GetPosition(mainCanvas).Y);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant set a video as a source to `BitmapImage`.

> BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(); 
>   await bm.SetSourceAsync(stream);

You need to use `MediaPlayerElement` to play a video. Have a look at the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement#examples).

## Edit

> I have to delete the drag and drop for image. Is there a way to detect
>   whether the item Im dropping is image or video?

```
    private async void mainGrid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Width = 200;
        img.Height = 150;
        BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();
        MediaPlayerElement mediaPlayerElement = new MediaPlayerElement();
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        {
            var storageItems = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
            foreach (StorageFile file in storageItems)
            {
                if (file.FileType == ".mp4")
                {
                    mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
                    mainGrid.Children.Add(mediaPlayerElement);
                }
                else
                {
                    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                    await bm.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                    img.Source = bm;
                    mainGrid.Children.Add(img);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Alright, so I managed make it such that I can drag and drop mediaelement (video) in. But to do so, I have to delete the drag and drop for image. Is there a way to detect whether the item Im dropping is image or video?                                                                                         Edit: how do I paste my current code?

Comment: You can always check the FileType of the storage file and handle your code based on that.

Comment: Im so sorry I really dont know how to do it haha, would you mind helping me?

Comment: Okay sure. I ll add it in my answer

Comment: I have added the solution